# How to write Tables in SQL with a Disjoint Connection

Tags: sql, database, relationship

So I have three tables which I want to create with a disjoint Connection. These are person, Tenant and employee. 
So every person must either be a Tenant or an employee, never both.
I create a Person table with the PersonID primary key, and tenant and Employee as two separate tables whose Primary Keys are both Foreign Keys linking back to the Person(PersonID).
How do i create a Disjoint here where every Person can only be either a Tenant or an Employee? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  - Can you provide some example data and what you expect to return? This sounds like it should be a simple JOIN.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, which will pick out every person who is EITHER a person OR an employee:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT person.*,
             CASE WHEN employee.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_employee,
             CASE WHEN tenant.id   IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_tenant
      FROM person LEFT JOIN employee on person.id = employee.id
                  LEFT JOIN tenant on person.id = tenant.id) AS tA
WHERE tA.is_employee <> tA.is_person
```

Make sure that the id columns are all indexed.